# Using Existing CAS to authenticate users on another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cas

First time posting, but been a long time reader. I'm tasked to use my university's CAS to authenticate users on a ruby on rails app. I have my welcome page that has a link to the signon screen that then is forwarded to a dashboard with a ticket in the url. I'm a bit confused on how to take that ticket and authenticate the ticket in order to get the info of the user that has logged in. Please help. THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your application must take the ticket returned by the user's browser and make a direct call back to CAS and "turn in" the ticket to retrieve the actual user information.

You basically have three protocols/endpoints that can be used: /cas/validate, /cas/serviceValidate, and /cas/samlValidate. See http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol for details.

But instead of writing your own solution, check out [Ruby on Rails CAS Clients](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Ruby+on+Rails+CAS+Clients) for a couple of options.